# Histogram with discontinuous x-axis

Tags: r

I need to realize an histogram in R. I add a picture to represent the desired results. I had tried to use both `ggplot2` and the base function `hist`. I used this code (ggplot) to get the basic histogram, but I would like to add the option to set the x-axis as shown in the figure (exactly the same values). Can someone tell me how to do that?

My imput file `DataLig2` contains a list of objects and for each of these is associated a value (N..of.similar..Glob.Sum...0.83..ligandable.pockets). I need to plot the frequencies of all the reported values. The lowest value is 1 and the highest is 28. There aren't values from 16 to 27 so I would like to skip thi range in my plot.

example of imput file:

```
Object;N..of.similar..Glob.Sum...0.83..ligandable.pockets
1b47_A_001;3
4re2_B_003;1
657w_H_004_13
1gtr_A_003;28
...
```

my script:

```
ggplot(dataLig2, aes(dataLig2$N..of.similar..Glob.Sum...0.83..ligandable.pockets, fill = group)) + geom_histogram(color="black") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("1-5" = "olivedrab1",
                               "6-10" = "limegreen",
                               "11-28" = "green4"))
```

Can you also suggest a script with the `hist` base function to get the same graph (with spaced bars as in the figure shown)? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Can you add some data for us to work with in a reproducible format? Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: I add more info. The important thing is that I understand how I can skip the 16-27 interval in the x-axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *ggplot*, set x as factor, missing numbers as "...", and set to plot unused levels, see example:

```
library(ggplot2)

# reproducible example data
# where 8 and 9 is missing
set.seed(1); d <- data.frame(x = sample(c(1:7, 10), 100, replace = TRUE))

# add missing 8 and 9 as labels
d$x1 <- factor(d$x, levels = 1:10, labels = c(1:7, "...", "...", 10))

#compare
cowplot::plot_grid(
  ggplot(d, aes(x)) +
    geom_bar() +
    ggtitle("before") +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:10),
  ggplot(d, aes(x = x1)) +
    geom_bar() +
    scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
    ggtitle("after"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! You were very clear and kind! At this point I would like to take this opportunity to ask for another advice. I would like to color the bars with different colors depending on the value of the x-axis. For example I would assign for x = 1 the color orange, for the bar with x = 2 the color yellow, for the bars 3=<x=<5 the color light green and for the bars from 6 to 28 the color dark green. How do I enter this condition?

Comment: @TommasoPalomba ask as a new question, please.